# Where is my program taking this output from?

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

I wrote a simple code and I tried to execute it:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a[] {0,2,4,6,8};
    int *b = a;
    for (int i=0;i<25;i++) {
        cout << *b << endl;
        *b++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

...but the result is confusing:

[image: Output from the code]

Can someone explain what the program output after the first 5 numbers?

Before anyone comments, I found where the problem is, but I'm still curious where it took those numbers from.

Comment: This is undefined behavior. Anything can happen when you dereference the pointer that points past the bounds of the array.

Comment: You are reading past the end of the array into surrounding memory, which is *undefined behavior*. Your array has only 5 values in it, but your loop is reading 25 values from it. Fix your loop.

Comment: Also `*b++;` should be just `b++;` (or `++b;`), or you can omit it completely and increment the pointer in your print statement eg `cout << *b++ << endl;`

Answer (score 2):

No rule requires or prohibits any particular behavior. So there's really no way for anyone to know what your particular combination of software and workflow happened to do.

This is called "undefined behavior".

Requiring something particular to happen in cases like this would add cost and complexity to compilers and optimizers and likely reduce performance of correct code. So there are no requirements.